# JMeter SQLServer Database Load test

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to set up a basic load test using Jmeter against SQLServer 2008 R2 database. However, I am getting an error when running the test with just one user.

Response message: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user XXX. ClientConnectionId:.

Here are my JDBC Connection configurations
Database URL: jdbc:sqlserver://Servername:1433;DatabaseName=XXX_DB;
JDBC Driver Class: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

I have tried few things but had no luck.

-Downloaded and installed the jdbc driver - sqljdbc4.jar
- Changed the security mode to mixed in SQL server management studio
- Added the directory paths of the jdbc driver in testplan

Tried a couple of other things but had no luck. Please provide some suggestions to resolve the issue. Looking forward for help.

Cheers,
Deshdeep.

Answer (score 1):

First download JDBC jar files from below link i have shared:

http://tinyurl.com/o5hgpmt

Extract all *.jar files to:  C:\apache-jmeter-2.11\lib

then start JMeter

and in your JDBC Connection Configuration element write below connections as per your database:

Database URL: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://x.x.x.x:1433;DatabaseName=yourdatabase;

JDBC Driver class: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver

Username: give username of the sql server database
Password: give password of the sql server database

My connection is successful..
Hope this helps every body..